# How do I convert Python Code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x

I was trying to convert my code from Python to JS, because I want to use HTML with my JavaScript code. My question is, how do I convert this code from Python to JavaScript without parsing Python. Sorry for the messy wording.

```py
#Python Code


import requests

import json

import datetime

  url = https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=jpmf&interval=60min&apikey=testkey


  response = requests.get(url)

  assert response.status_code == 200

  data =json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: Check out `fetch` in JavaScript.

Comment: @Phix She/He needs to convert python codes so the target is backend js engine ( like node). There is no fetch as embed lib there. ```node-fetch``` is independent

Comment: Hi @ali, just for future reference, it's *really* not a good idea to post your real apikey in your questions. Anyone will be able to use it :(

Comment: I realise this is not any sort of sensitive data, but still felt the need to bring up the security concerns :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any frameworks:

```js
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=jpmf&interval=60min&apikey=testkey', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Just see node [documents](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback)